# Getting an error while trying to make a library management system

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image #PIL -> Pillow
from tkinter import messagebox
from AddBook import *
from DeleteBook import *
from ViewBooks import *
from IssueBook import *
​
root = Tk()
root.title("Rcis Library")
root.minsize(width=400,height=400)
root.geometry("600x500")
​
headingFrame1 = Frame(root,bg="#FFBB00",bd=5)
headingFrame1.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.6,relheight=0.16)
headingLabel = Label(headingFrame1, text="Welcome to \n DataFlair Library", bg='black', fg='white', font=('Courier',15))
headingLabel.place(relx=0,rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1
​
btn1 = Button(root,text="Add Book",bg='black', fg='white', command=addBook)
btn1.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.4, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn2 = Button(root,text="Delete Book",bg='black', fg='white', command=delete)
btn2.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.5, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn3 = Button(root,text="View Book List",bg='black', fg='white', command=View)
btn3.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.6, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn4 = Button(root,text="Issue Book",bg='black', fg='white', command = issueBook)
btn4.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.7, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn5 = Button(root,text="Return Book",bg='black', fg='white', command = returnBook)
btn5.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.8, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
root.mainloop()
```

```
File "<ipython-input-16-8717138cafeb>", line 19
        btn1 = Button(root,text="Add Book",bg='black', fg='white', command=addBook)
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image #PIL -> Pillow
from Tkinter import messagebox
from AddBook import *
from DeleteBook import *
from ViewBooks import *
from IssueBook import *
​
root = Tk()
root.title("Library")
root.minsize(width=400,height=400)
root.geometry("600x500")
​
headingFrame1 = Frame(root,bg="#FFBB00",bd=5)
headingFrame1.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.6,relheight=0.16)
headingLabel = Label(headingFrame1, text="Welcome to \n DataFlair Library", bg='black', fg='white', font=('Courier',15))
headingLabel.place(relx=0,rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
​
btn1 = Button(root,text="Add Book Details",bg='black', fg='white', command=addBook)
btn1.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.4, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn2 = Button(root,text="Delete Book",bg='black', fg='white', command=delete)
btn2.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.5, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn3 = Button(root,text="View Book List",bg='black', fg='white', command=View)
btn3.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.6, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn4 = Button(root,text="Issue Book to Student",bg='black', fg='white', command = issueBook)
btn4.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.7, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
    
btn5 = Button(root,text="Return Book",bg='black', fg='white', command = returnBook)
btn5.place(relx=0.28,rely=0.8, relwidth=0.45,relheight=0.1)
root.mainloop()
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3991be32e0bf> in <module>
2 from PIL import ImageTk,Image #PIL -> Pillow
3 from tkinter import messagebox
----> 4 from AddBook import *
5 from DeleteBook import *
6 from ViewBooks import *\
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AddBook'
```

My code shows the error No module named 'AddBook' please help ?

Comment: You are doing `from AddBook import *`. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure, I am new to coding. I copied this code from https://data-flair.training/blogs/library-management-system-python-project/comment-page-2/#comment-59960

Comment: Then you should have a local file `AddBook` somewhere. Did you just copy the code or download the entire porject?

Comment: Also, how are you executing the script?

Comment: you forgot closing `)` in line before `btn1 = ...` - and this gives `SyntaxError`

Comment: `import *` is not preferred - see more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: first check `Current Working Directory` - `os.getcwd()`. Maybe Python runs in different folder than you expect and it can't find file `AddBook.py`

Comment: @MegaIng I downloaded the copy but I don't know what to do with it after extracting it, I am using jupyter to execute the script.

Comment: @MegaIng I have the AddBook downloaded on my system, it's stored in a new folder